Why is determining "Firebase Function Python exec prefix [ ]" an issue?
I am working with python 3.12.3 and want to deploy my functions to the firebase functions console using firebase deploy --only functions.
I am using the minimal reproducible example
from firebase_functions import https_fn

@https_fn.on_request()
def hello_world(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    return https_fn.Response("Hello, World!")

However, i always get this error:

Build failed with status: FAILURE and message: failed to build: determining Python exec prefix: []

I already removed the venv multiple times, but it did not change anything. The logs do not say anything beyond the error message above.
Did anyone encounter this before?

I found the problem myself: I had another python installation from which I created the venv.
Using MacOS, the installation should be in /usr/local.
